# Changing a font with css?

Tags: css, bigcartel

Im trying to change my primary font on bigcartel. Heres what I have so far:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'kollektifregular';
    src: url('kollektif-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('kollektif-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

The font isn’t changing on my site so please let me know what to fix, thank you!

Comment: W3School: [`@font-face`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp) and [`font`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Using `@font-face` *defines* a font, but does not apply it. If you want to apply it somewhere, you can simply say:

```
h1 {
    font-family: 'kollektifregular';
}
```

or if you want to use it everywhere:

```
* {
    font-family: 'kollektifregular';
}
```